# sample size calculation for interrupted time series

Tags: time-series, panel-data, sample-size, statistical-power

I am trying to do a sample size calculation for a interrupted time series study design.

I am reading [Zhang's](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21640554) simulation-based power calculation paper and [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2714195/).

It seems to me that for a time series analysis the sample size means number of time points, see Zhang's paper in page 1254 under table 2.

And they have never mentioned that at each time point how many "sample" were needed.

Such as we can measure one person's blood pressure for 100 days(50 days before taking a drug and 50 days after taking the drug) then the sample size will be "100" by the definition of above papers.

We also can measure 1000 people's blood pressure for 100 days still 50 days before taking a drug and 50 days after taking the drug and measure the means of the 1000 people for every time.  By the definition the sample size still is 100 (100 time points).

However, if I want to say that the drug has some effects, I would say the second one will be more valid.

My question is how the time series deal with the "sample size" at each time point?

Are there sample size calculation methods to deal with both number of time points (sample size for time series) and a "sample size" at each observation time?

Comment: What you describe in the example is called panel data